# Error al intentar instalar elibyy/tcpdf-laravel por composer

Tags: php, laravel-5, pdf

Quiero instalar el paquete **[tcpdf-laravel](https://packagist.org/packages/elibyy/tcpdf-laravel)**, para ellos ejecuto el comando
`composer require elibyy/tcpdf-laravel` esto me arroja el siguiente error:

[image: tcpdf-laravel]

**NOTA:** lo que aparece antes de ejecutar el comando es que ejecute `composer update` para ver si actualizando si instalaba `tcpdf`, pero no :'(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que la versión 5.4 es para `laravel 5.4`, porque requiere de la ultima version de `laravel collective` y  laravel collective de otra version y bla bla bla, en fin, la solución fue modificar el archivo `composer.json` y especificar la versión del paquete

```
{
    "require": {
        "elibyy/tcpdf-laravel": "5.3.*"
    }
}
```

.

O también pueden actualizar `laravel a 5.4`.